# Фильтрация с использованием метасимволов в MySQL

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT cust_contact
FROM Customers
WHERE cust_contact LIKE '[JM]%'
ORDER BY oust contact;
```

Мне надо вывести все клиентов имя которых начинаются с буквы J либо M, но у меня этот запрос не работает. Оно должно работать, никаких явных ошибок нет, как мне кажется.
Метасимволы (_,%) работают, а вот метасимвол - квадратные [ ] - не работает.
Или метасимвол квадратная скобка не поддерживается на моем сервере. 
У меня версия сервера MySQL 5.5.54

Я взял эту запрос из [книги Бена Форта](http://forcoder.ru/web-other/sql-za-10-minut-1253) с 70 стр.

Comment: `like` в MySQL так не умеет. используйте `regexp`/`rlike` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html

Comment: Напишите тогда уж просто `WHERE LEFT(cust_contact, 1) IN ('J', 'M')` - всё одно фуллскан.